# How to generate number between 0.00 and 98, cryptographically, with PHP?

Tags: php

I need to generate a number between 0.00 and 100, and I want it to be truly random (cryptographically secure). How can I do this with PHP?

All answers I seen don't do it cryptographically, or they do it in whole numbers (where as I need two numbers after a decimal)

Comment: You are expected to **try to write the code yourself**. After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My approach would be:

- create random value from 0 to 9800
- divide that value by 100, to get 0.00 to 98.00

If you have PHP 7, this is really easy, by use of the [`random_int()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.random-int.php) function

```
$randValue = round(random_int(0, 9800)/ 100, 2);
```

[**Live demo**](https://ideone.com/vjfx5M)

For older versions of PHP, there is no native function I know that would be considered cryptographically safe. Good solutions rely on 3rd party packages such as `mbcrypt` or `openssl`. I would probably use the polyfill that has received PHP's official support.

It is [hosted on github](https://github.com/paragonie/random_compat) and should work with PHP 5.2 to 5.6

Comment: Would this ever generate a number with a decimal that isn't `.00`? If not, then what's the difference between generating a number between 0 and 98 and just appending the decimal at the end?

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton sure it would.  It is rounded to 2 decimal spaces

Comment: Your totally right I'm not sure what my brain was thinking LMAO

Comment: and if you *don't* have PHP7 there's [`random_compat`](https://github.com/paragonie/random_compat) which backports `random_int()` and `random_bytes()`.

Comment: very nice solution.

Comment: @Sammitch thanks. I already linked to `random_compat` in my solution. The last line.